# How do I set QComboBox height?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox, qtstylesheets

So i've been working with pyqt5 and i'm trying to set the height (size not position) of a qcombobox. Not the drop-down list, the actual box. I've tried everything and nothing seems to work. setFixedSize only changes the width of the box and then its y position on the main window instead of its actual height (seems pretty weird that I wonder if its a bug) and stylesheet stuff seems to only affect the drop down list and/or the line edit but not the frame of the qcombobox. Does anyone have any suggestions?? Literally just trying to make the damn thing like 2px bigger vertically!

Here's what i've got:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QComboBox, QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize

class combo(QDialog):

        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

            containers = ['1','2','3','4','5']
            cbox = QComboBox(self)
            cbox.setFixedSize(80, 30)
            cbox.setStyleSheet('QComboBox {font: 16pt Arial}')
            cbox.setEditable(True)
            cbox.lineEdit().setFixedSize(50, 18)
            cbox.addItems(containers)
            cbox.setSizeAdjustPolicy(1)
            cbox.move(50, 50)

            for i in range(len(containers)):
                cbox.model().setData(cbox.model().index(i,0), QSize(80, 30), Qt.SizeHintRole)

            cbox.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        demo = combo()
        demo.show()

        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It should be enough to set the minimum height, but that also depends on other aspects. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (if you're using Designer, provide the ui file too)

Comment: Already tried that. Both with setMinimumHeight and with style sheets. It just shifts the vertical position of the box.

Comment: Changing the combo's line edit size is not only useless, but counterproductive (it will change the line edit, the combo won't be affected). Are you completely sure that the size is not changed? Have you tried higher values for the height (I mean *very* high values, so that the difference should be evident)? Consider that the widget size is not always the *exact* rectangle they "show", as styles add internal margins to most widgets. Besides that, please provide a *fully* [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not just some snippets.

Comment: Done that too there's definitely no change! Edited my post with fully reproducible code

Comment: Try it `cbox.lineEdit().setFixedSize(56, 30)  # - (50, 18)`

Comment: I tried setting the fixed height *of the combo* to a high number (150) and it works (result on PyQt5.12 on Linux: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nsjxi.png), so I cannot reproduce your issue. Please specify your configuration and versions for both your Operating System and PyQt.

Comment: PyQt5.14.1 on macOS High Sierra (10.13)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on macOS too. No luck setting minimumSize, etc. I managed to solve this by setting the combo box style to Fusion. Then the control height respects the setMinimumHeight(...)

Sorry for the code in C++, Python code will be similar.

```
cbox->setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));
```